# Do I need a passport book if I am flying from Reynosa, Mexico to Cancun Mexico?

Tags: air-travel, passports

I am a US citizen and Im traveling to Reynosa, Mexico and then taking a flight from there to Cancun, Mexico. Will I need a passport traveling within Mexico.